# Table-like layout in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am designing an android application. I want to achieve the table-like layout (in picture shown below) in XML. 
Please guide me through.

[image: Layout]

Comment: I can't see any picture , is this because u don't know how put a picture or my university is blocking that access!

Comment: I can see the picture. Why can't you ?

Comment: really ,then my university wifi sucks

Comment: How do I show you the picture, then ?